# How to use UIBlurEffect for Buttons in Swift

Tags: button, swiftui, lag, uiblureffect

I'm trying to add .systemThinMaterial to my SwiftUI buttons but after 8 buttons it starts lagging when I scroll. Is it too intensive to use that for button? or em I doing it wrong?

```
struct BlurryButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

Then for my Button style I use

```
struct DefaultStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label

            .background(BlurryButton(style: .systemThinMaterial))

            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.7 : 1.0)
          }
       }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Include your actual buttons. Note that you don't need `UIViewRepresentable`. You can just do it totally in SwiftUI. Do ` .background(style: thinMaterial)`.

Comment: @Sweeper Apparently using shadows on buttons kills the performance and makes it lag. Got any ideas to keep the shadow effect without having the laggy scrolling? or is `.shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.25), radius: 1.5, x: 0, y: 0)` wrong and I'm not doing shadows right?